# how to download jpg,png,pdf,doc.ppt,rtf,etc file from the google drive in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, download, google-drive-api

I am new iPhone developer.I am developing iPhone app in this app Google drive integration it is successfully.but I want to download jpg,png,pdf,doc.ppt,rtf,etc file are download.

all file and folder display in Table view.I want do download the selected file from the table view.so how can do this ?

I am read this link https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get but i can not understand.here how to call all this function.

I want to download file's from Google Drive and save in document directory.

I am try this code.

NSString *downloadedString = file.downloadUrl; // file is GTLDriveFile

```
        NSLog(@"%@",file.downloadUrl);

        GTMHTTPFetcher *fetcher = [self.driveService.fetcherService  fetcherWithURLString:downloadedString];

        [fetcher beginFetchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSError *error)
        {
            if (error == nil)
            {
                if(data != nil)
                {

                    GTLDriveFile *file = [driveFiles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

                    NSString *filename=file.title;
                    //this variable globalObj.documentPath is global variable for document directory path.
                    filename = [globalObj.documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",filename]];
                     filename=[filename stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"file:/private" withString:@"file:///"];
                    NSLog(@"File name : %@",filename);
                    NSURL *targetURL=[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:downloadedString];
                    NSData* Data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:targetURL];
                    [Data writeToFile:filename atomically:YES];
                    NSLog(@"my path:%@",filename);


                }
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Error - %@", error.description);
            }
        }];
```

so places help me.I want to download file and save in document directory.
any link for code places suggestion me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you does not have to do all this stuff.
here is just simple code
image url is from dropbox.

NSString *stringURL = @"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/pquhnr5pt37uk6q/backkk.jpeg?dl=1&token_hash=AAEXBejAXoD__RPMBom6nL2F5_Uhu62ed0puhtLIt2FGug";

NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];

NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

if ( urlData )
{
  NSArray       *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"yourfile.png"];

[urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

}

and finally you can represent it any way you want.

If you want to download large data.then use Threading concept.

Comment: I am try this code but It not working.I am downloading from google drive. file.downloadUrl line to get download link in google drive.so how can do this places explain me. thank for replay.

Answer (score 1):

if you use imageview programetically then write below code.....                                                                                                                                                                               myimg=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 100, 100, 100)];
 myimg.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/pquhnr5pt37uk6q/backkk.jpeg?dl=1&token_hash=AAEXBejAXoD__RPMBom6nL2F5_Uhu62ed0puhtLIt2FGug"]]];
                                                                                                                                                                                               [self.view 
addSubview:myimg];                                                                                                                                       it's working

Comment: I want to download file from Google drive.file like this doc,ppt,rtf,pdf,png,jpg.so how can do this ?thanks for replay.